# Which tool can I use on Mac in order to create an Analysis Services tabular model?

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I work on macOs and I need to create an Analysis Services tabular model, from some data stored on an Azure Storage. I've seen that, in order to create a tabular model, it can be done from Visual Studio with the Analysis Services Projects extension, but that one do not seem to be available for Mac. Also read that it can be done from SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server Data Tools, but both of them aren't available for Mac either.

Which tool can I use on mi Mac in order to create an Analysis Services tabular model?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Visual Studio or Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT - a subset of VS which is free) on a PC to create an AAS model. SSMS and Data Studio, can't be used to create the model, however, can be used to process and administer it.
Maybe look at an [Azure Data Science VM](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-gb/marketplace/apps/microsoft-dsvm.dsvm-win-2019?tab=Overview) which has VS Community on it and install the VS AAS module for it.